Can't add Widget Extension on WatchOS Target
I can't select my Companion App Target in the Selection Many for "Embed in" in the add Target File. It's a Companion App for a Flutter App.
I add the target via File -> New -> Target -> WatchOS -> WidgetExtension

The minimum version for the flutter project is iOS 14 and the watch watchOS 10.
I tried readding my WatchTarget but it didn't work that time either. I made a dummy project with a default iOS App (No Flutter) and default WatchOS App and there I had the option to select my Companion Target.
checking Configuration Intent also changes nothing for the outcome.
I also tried adding one into another Runner (Flutter) Project with an Companion App and I run into the same Issue there.
